# Progress bar isn't showing up. Not recognizing {i}

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a progress circle out of data points which are represented as {i}. I have used Javascript to pull the code but it's not recognizing it in the inspect element and showing up in elements.

Here is the code that is pulling the data for data-dots and data-percent:

```
<div class="box">
                    <div class="circle" data-dots="80" data-percent="55"></div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <big>55%</big>
                        <small>Project Management</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the Javascript that is pulling the code for the animation

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
circles.forEach(elem=>{
  var dots = elem.getAttribute("data-dots");
  var marked = elem.getAttribute("data-percent");
  var percent = Math.floor(dots*marked/100);
  var points = "";
  var rotate = 360 / dots;


  for(let i = 0 ; i < dots ; i++) {
    points += '<div class="points" style="--i:${i}; --rot:${rotate}deg"></div>';
  }
  elem.innerHTML = points;

  const pointsMarked = elem.querySelectorAll('.points');
  for(let i = 0; i<percent ; i++){
    pointsMarked[i].classList.add('marked')
  } 
});
```

And here is the styling:

```
.circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle .points{
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--i)*var(--rot))) translateY(-60px);
}

.points.marked{
    animation: glow 0.04s linear forwards;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--i)*0.05s);
}
```

I've checked everything over and over but keep getting the same results and the circle is showing up as a small circle on the screen pulling this back from the animation. Not sure where it's going wrong

```
element.style {
    --i: ${i};
    --rot: ${rotate}deg;
}
```

I've tried using the individual data points but obvious the formula will make that alot easier instead of writing out all 80 points especially for 4 different circles

Comment: Template strings use backticks, not apostrophes/"single quotes".

Comment: Why not use HTML's `<progress>` element?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Don't know how I missed this. Thank you

Comment: But Ronnie has a point too: this is something HTML already has an element for =)